# SQL balancy calculation Ordered by Date

Tags: mysql, sql, join, subquery, union

I have 2 tables AmountIn and AmountOut.

The first table Amountin looks like :

AmountIn

```
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| account| date         | AmountIn  |
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| A      |  2017/2/6    | 200       |
| A      |  2017/2/5    | 100       |
| A      |  2017/2/5    | 500       |
| B      |  2017/2/1    | 1000      |
| B      |  2017/2/1    | 2000      |
| C      |  2017/1/20   | 25        |
+--------+----+---------+-----------+
```

And the second one looks like:

AmountOut

```
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| account| date         |AmountOut  |
+--------+--------------+-----------+
| A      |  2017/2/8    | 200       |
| A      |  2017/2/7    | 100       |
| A      |  2017/2/6    | 500       |
| B      |  2017/2/2    | 1000      |
| B      |  2017/2/1    | 2000      |
| C      |  2017/1/20   | 25        |
+--------+----+---------+-----------+
```

Now I want a query that will display result as follow:
ForAccountA

```
+--------+--------------+----------+-----------+------------+
| account| date         | AmountIn | AmountOut | Balancy    |
+--------+--------------+-------- -+-----------+------------+
| A      |  2017/2/8    | 0        | 200       | 0          |
| A      |  2017/2/7    | 0        | 100       | 200        |
| A      |  2017/2/6    | 200      | 0         | 300        |
| A      |  2017/2/6    | 0        | 500       | 100        |
| A      |  2017/2/5    | 100      | 0         | 600        |
| A      |  2017/2/5    | 500      | 0         | 500        |
+--------+----+---------+----------+-----------+------------+
```

this mean to union both tables and calculate  `balancy`  as :

```
last balance + AmountIn - AmounOut
```

My code is :

```
select
    t.*,
    @sum := if(@account = account, 
                @sum + AmountIn - AmountOut,
                if((@account := account) is not null,
                    AmountIn - AmountOut, 0)
            ) balance
from (
    select
        *
    from (
        select
            1 x,
            account,
            date,
            AmountIn,
            0 AmountOut
        from AmountIn
        union all
        select
            0 x,
            account,
            date,
            0 AmountIn,
            AmountOut
        from AmountOut
    ) t order by account, date, x
) t cross join (select @account := null, @sum := 0) t2
```

But it give me result on date ascending i want it to be ordered by date descending. I neet o see  the last operaions on top , otherwise when data get a lo i will be hard o scroll down or go o next pages
Please help

Comment: `t order by account, date desc, x`

Comment: in this case the 'balanacy' will get mess, not correct

Comment: Added `mysql` tag based on the non-standard syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with a balance that builds by txn by txn. I use unionall (without join) to build the initial table as in your example it seems like you don't want rows with both `amountin` and `amountout`:

```
select * 
from (
select 
@cnt := If(@prev=account , @cnt+1,1) rown, a.*,
@balance := if(  @prev=account, @balance + amountin - amountout, amountin - amountout) balance,                                                           
@prev := account prev  from 
(select account, date, amountin, 0 amountout from amountin
union all
select account, date, 0, amountout from amountout) a, (select @cnt := 1) b, (select @prev :='') c, (select @balance :=0) bal
order by account, date
    ) r
    order by account, rown desc, date desc
```

[Here is a working exmaple with your data](http://rextester.com/FVGD93278)

Comment: this is perfect and beautiful , thank very much ,  how about if tables are 3 ,we add one more table 'thirdTable'  which mean 'balance = lastbalance +amountin +thirdamount-amountout' the third table has the same structure as others

Comment: Thank you again, and sorry for the late +1,  i would appreciate if can give how would be like